# In StringGrid, goEditing prevents the MouseDown event from firing

Tags: delphi

In a string grid I turned on goEditing so that the user doesn't have to click to get into the editor.

Now when they right click then get the pop-up below, rather than my MouseDown event being called.

Is there a way to turn off this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goEditing mode means that the focused grid cell always contains an active edit control.  Without goEditing, the edit control is not made visible until the user clicks to enter edit mode.

In goEditing mode, when you right click you're right clicking on the edit control, not on the grid.  Consequently the popup menu that results is the edit control's popup menu rather than the grid's popup menu.

If you want to override/replace the edit control's default popup menu with your own, you may be able to do that by either modifying the edit control instance that the grid uses (there's only one edit control instance that is moved around from cell to cell as focus moves) or by specifying your own cell editor type.

I'm sorry I can't be more specific here - it's been more than ten years since I last worked on the innards of the Delphi grid controls.

Comment: Thanks, Danny!  I saw the "dthorpe" signature and immediately was reminded of your name, which I had seen in various places over the years when you still involved with the product! Nice to see you're still around and answering Delphi questions!  -- What bothers me about this operation of the grid is that it's moded. The user gets different results from a right-mouse click depending on whether he's begun typing. Isn't that non-standard? (I'm not complaining, just trying to understand!)

Comment: Yes, the string grid is a bit of a red-headed stepchild.  Most of the development effort went into the TDBGrid.  Depending on your scenario, you might get better results by setting up your data in an in-memory table and using the TDBGrid on it instead of using a TStringGrid.

Comment: Thanks again! And for the suggestion of the TDBGrid